# O paraquedas desce de cabeca pra baixo. Como inverte-lo?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Eu fiz um foguete no Unity que consigo fazer decolar e pousar depois de cinco segundos. Porém, ele pousa desse jeito:

[image: Foguete]

Eu quero fazer com que ele chegue ao chão com o paraquedas para cima. Como que eu posso fazer isso pelo código?

Código que eu tenho, até agora:

```
double t = 5.0;

void Update () {
GameObject Paraquedas;
GameObject CorpoNariz;
CorpoNariz = GameObject.Find("Corpo_Nariz");
Paraquedas = GameObject.Find("Paraquedas");
    rigidbody.AddForce(transform.up * 15);
    t -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (t <= 0) {
    Destroy (CorpoNariz);
    Paraquedas.renderer.enabled = true;
    rigidbody.AddForce(-transform.up * 50);
    rigidbody.drag = 5;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Qual o objetivo do `transform.Rotate(Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);`? Me parece que meramente o remover resolveria o problema.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal foi algo que fiz para ver se resolvia meu problema, mas não fez nada. como é indiferente vou remover do post

Comment: O paraquedas está virado para cima na posição na cena? Nada deveria fazer o foguete girar então.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Esse é o foguete antes de decolar: http://i.imgur.com/HicIVbQ.png. Ele pousa na mesma posição que decola (sem a ponta, para poder sair o paraquedas). Eu tenho que fazer com que ele fique de cabeça para baixo, para que o paraquedas fique do jeito correto.

Comment: Algumas perguntas: qual é o objeto em que o código está sendo executado (isto é, que tem o componente *rigidbody*)? por que você lhe adiciona uma força "pra cima" a cada quadro (chamada de *update*)? e por que você o força "pra baixo" depois de 5 segundos (isso era algo pra gravidade fazer, não?)?

Comment: 1) É o foguete todo.
2) Porque ele tem que subir...
3) Porque ele tem que descer... (sou novo no Unity, não sabia se tem outro jeito de fazer ele cair, então fiz assim, mas aceito outras sugestões).

Comment: Entendi. Bom, idealmente você deveria adicionar força no foguete apenas quando uma aceleração ocorresse (talvez no pressionamento de uma tecla?). Já fazer o foguete cair é algo que a gravidade vai fazer pra você.

Comment: Mas, sobre o paraquedas, pelo que você respondeu ao @GuilhermeBernal, o paraquedas abre na traseira do foguete, é isso? E por isso você gostaria de inverter o foguete?

Comment: @LuizVieira isso

Comment: Ok. Vou tentar preparar uma resposta. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui está uma sugestão de como você pode fazer o que quer (desculpe, fiz em C# por costume, mas é trivial converter para javascript):

```csharp
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Disparar : MonoBehaviour {

    // Funçao de atualizaçao quadro a quadro
    void Update () {

        // So loga as informaçoes
        Debug.Log (rigidbody.velocity.magnitude);
        Debug.Log (noChao ());

        // Acelera se o jogador apertar a tecla ESPACO
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            acelera ();

        // Quando detectar que a velocidade inverteu (ficou negativa no y e magnitude bem pequena,
        // ou seja, o foguete parou la no alto), aplica uma força para girar.
        if (!noChao () && rigidbody.velocity.y < 0 && rigidbody.velocity.magnitude <= 1)
            //gira();
            StartCoroutine(fazRetorno());
    }

    // Acelera se o jogador clicar no foguete
    void OnMouseDown() {
        acelera();
    }

    // Acelera o foguete aplicando uma força para a sua direçao "cima".
    void acelera() {
        rigidbody.AddForce(transform.up * 2000);
    }

    // Gira o foguete aplicando uma força para a sua direçao direita a partir de seu topo.
    void gira() {
        Vector3 ponta = transform.position;
        ponta.y += renderer.bounds.size.y / 2;
        rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition (transform.right * 20, ponta);
    }

    // Indica se o foguete esta colidindo com o chao
    bool noChao() {
        return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, collider.bounds.extents.y + 0.1f);
    }

    // Gira o foguete 180 graus sobre o eixo X, fazendo-o inverter completamente a direçao de subida
    IEnumerator fazRetorno() {

        Quaternion angulo = Quaternion.Euler(180, 0, 0);
        float velocidade = 0.5f;

        while(Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, angulo) > 0)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, angulo, Time.deltaTime * velocidade);
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }  
        transform.rotation = angulo;
    }

}
```

Basicamente a ideia é que a partir de uma interação do usuário (clique ou teclado), uma força é adicionada ao foguete (eu testei com um paralelepipedo). A cada quadro, ele verifica se o foguete parou lá no alto (ou seja, não está no chão e a velocidade no eixo y foi invertida e está beeeemmm pequena - o que significa a magnitude menor do que 1). Se aconteceu isso, ele simplesmente aplica outra força no topo do foguete pra fazê-lo girar.

Esse exemplo faz com que o foguete suba verticalmente e vá desacelerando até parar lá no alto, então vai girar e começar a cair também verticalmente. Você precisará ajustar os valores da força para obter um efeito bacana como desejado.

> **EDIT**: Fiz uma nova função chamada `fazRetorno` que não usa física e simplesmente rotaciona o foguete sem adicionar nenhuma força
>   lateral. Talvez isso seja mais próximo do que você quer. Ela usa
>   recursos bacanas do Unity que são o comando `yield` junto com a função
>   `Quaternion.Slerp`. Basicamente a execução do laço (`while`) que tem
>   dentro da função `fazRetorno` é diluida ao longo de vários quadros (o
>   `yield` faz isso) e a rotação para de 180º no eixo x (a variável
>   `angulo` indica isso) é "interpolada" segundo a velocidade configurada
>   na variável `velocidade`. Apesar dessa rotação não usar física, repare
>   que a "queda" do foguete é toda gerenciada pelo motor de física da
>   Unity (isto é, a única força adicionada foi no começo, no momento do
>   lançamento). :)

Se seu jogo você quizer que o foguete seja lançado em uma trajetória balística (uma parábola), basta combinar os vetores para adicionar a força nos eixos y (cima) e x ou z (frente e lado) no momento do lançamento. Para isso, basta somar os vetores:

```csharp
Vector3 forca = (transform.up * 2000) + (transform.right * 300);
rigidbody.AddForce(forca);
```

Usando o `rigidbody.velocity` você consegue saber a velocidade do foguete a todo o momento, e pode decidir por abrir o paraquedas. É outra opção.

Espero que ajude.

P.S.: Pra esse exemplo o seu foguete tem que ter também um `collider` (idealmente um `box collider`) além do `rigidbody`. :)

Comment: Testei o seu código na integra e tentei adaptar ao meu atual algumas coisas. O que consegui foi fazer o foguete ir mais pra direita na hora de pousar, mas ele desce com o paraquedas no chão, da mesma forma. Estou fazendo algo errado?

Comment: Bom, provavelmente você teria que adicionar uma força lateral maior e o foguete precisaria estar suficientemente alto para ter tempo de girar. Mas, fiz uma edição em que sugiro outra alternativa (função `fazRetorno`) que não usa  física pra girar o foguete. Talvez seja isso que vc quer.

Comment: ficou show! Mas depois de descer o foguete continua "andando" pra frente no chão. Sabe o que poderia ser?

Comment: Possivelmente não deu tempo de girar completamente e quando bateu no solo resultou em alguma força residual. Você pode capturar o evento de colisão com o solo (adicione o método `onCollisionBegin`, se eu não me engano) e ao colidir com o solo forçar uma parada completa fazendo `Rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(0,0,0);`. Não testei, mas deve funcionar.

Comment: P.S.: Talvez você precise também forçar a rotação de 180 graus depois de fazer a parada forçada. A última linha da função `fazRetorno` faz isso.